# How to restart postgresql automatically in case of difficulties

Tags: postgresql, debian

I have a postgresql (13) server installed under debian (started with systemd) which sometimes has difficulties to start due to disk space problems which seem ephemeral.

In such cases I would like to try 3 restarts automatically and normally I would do this with systemd facilities.

But the systemd controlfile contains these lines

```
# # restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# # so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# # problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# # automatic restarts.
# #Restart=on-failure
```

So I assumed that postgresql would take care of required restarts.
The logs files dont show several tries to restart the server.

The log from today:

```
2023-06-13 04:24:05.120 UTC [3663213] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.11 (Debian 13.11-0+deb11u1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
2023-06-13 04:24:05.121 UTC [3663213] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2023-06-13 04:24:05.121 UTC [3663213] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2023-06-13 04:24:05.122 UTC [3663213] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2023-06-13 04:24:05.138 UTC [3663214] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-06-13 04:22:16 UTC
2023-06-13 04:24:05.149 UTC [3663213] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2023-06-14 04:14:40.277 UTC [3663215] PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp": No space left on device
2023-06-14 04:14:40.281 UTC [3663213] LOG:  checkpointer process (PID 3663215) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2023-06-14 04:14:40.281 UTC [3663213] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2023-06-14 04:14:40.283 UTC [3663218] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2023-06-14 04:14:40.283 UTC [3663218] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2023-06-14 04:14:40.283 UTC [3663218] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2023-06-14 04:14:40.284 UTC [3663219] LOG:  could not write temporary statistics file "pg_stat/db_73929.tmp": No space left on device
2023-06-14 04:14:40.284 UTC [3663219] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat/db_1.tmp": No space left on device
2023-06-14 04:14:40.284 UTC [3663219] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat/db_0.tmp": No space left on device
2023-06-14 04:14:40.284 UTC [3663219] LOG:  could not close temporary statistics file "pg_stat/global.tmp": No space left on device
2023-06-14 04:14:40.288 UTC [3663213] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2023-06-14 04:14:40.349 UTC [3700734] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2023-06-14 04:09:40 UTC
2023-06-14 04:14:40.808 UTC [3700734] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2023-06-14 04:14:40.812 UTC [3700734] LOG:  redo starts at 1F/DA4EEA68
2023-06-14 04:14:40.816 UTC [3700734] LOG:  invalid record length at 1F/DA524770: wanted 24, got 0
2023-06-14 04:14:40.816 UTC [3700734] LOG:  redo done at 1F/DA524738
2023-06-14 04:14:40.832 UTC [3700734] PANIC:  could not write to file "pg_logical/replorigin_checkpoint.tmp": No space left on device
2023-06-14 04:14:40.833 UTC [3663213] LOG:  startup process (PID 3700734) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2023-06-14 04:14:40.833 UTC [3663213] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2023-06-14 04:14:40.836 UTC [3663213] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

So my question is :

What is the best way to assure that postgresql tries 3 restartes before giving up ?

Comment: "The logs files dont show several tries to restart the server."  So then what makes you think they are happening?

Comment: @jjanes: I sse that they don't happen, but I would prefer that they did and want to know how I should do it. I updated the question to make this clearer.

Comment: I see.  So it only tries to restart once, and then gives up, but you want it to retry several times.  I don't think there is away to do that directly inside PostgreSQL.  I think the first thing I'd worry about is why your storage is randomly appearing to be full and then also randomly fixing itself.  You could change systemd settings and then just keep in mind the warning it gives 'prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working'.  Maybe that doesn't bother you much.

Comment: @jjanes: Of course you are right, that it would be better to solve the real problem and I think I did that in the meantime.
As  a stop - gap measure restart with systemd seems te way to go then. Thank you !